# SSRS passing parameters as '?' to ODBC

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mysql-odbc-connector

I have a windows server in which I have installed SSRS to make some reports out of a mySQL database. SSRS is connected through "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver". I remember the reports working fine just before upgrading the ODBC driver but now I receive the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>           Query execution failed for dataset '****'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>               ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.17-13-57-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '? and O.created_at <=?' at line 14

There is no syntax errors in the query. When I fill the parameters manually and run it in DBeaver...no problems. But it seems as if the SSRS is passing the '?' as '?' itself not the parameters input.

Further info:

- I happened to see it in SOME queries but not all.
- When I add the parameter values in the Query builder and disable the parameter it runs with no problem.
- I believe it started when I updated the ODBC driver

Comment: Can you provide details on what ODBC driver you're using, including the version?